# HTTP POST response

Tags: http, post, esp32

I have a little problem. I wrote a program on ***ESP32*** which records some data and save it to SD card then data is read line by line and send to app which put it in postgres database. The problem is, sometimes data is being write to database long and sometimes it took like 0.5 sec, so i get response after 10 sec, sometimes after 5s, etc. Here is problem, on ESP I cant figure out how to wait to get response, my program just give me error but the data is sucessfully sent, it shows in database. So here is my question, how am I supposed to wait for response and then I can run rest of code.

And second question with the same program. As Im using sd card adapter and writing data to files, after i get **response = 200** from server I want to clear files. What I did is I just delete both files (Im saving data to 2 files) and when i need to write data again to those files I create them. I suppose it not the most optimal way of doing it but couldnt find any method to clear files content or I just missed it somehow. Any suggestion on how I could do it another way?

```
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && flag == false){
    createFile();
    HTTPClient http;
    http.begin("http://192.168.xx.xxx/xxxxxxx");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String h_str = String(h);
    if (h < 10)
    {
      h_str = "0" + String(h);
    }
    String m_str = String(m);
    if (m < 10)
    {
      m_str = "0" + String(m);
    }
    String s_str = String(s);
    if (s < 10)
    {
      s_str = "0" + String(s);
    }

    String totalTime_HMS = h_str + ":" + m_str + ":" + s_str;
    //Srial.println(totalTime_HMS)

    doc["name"] = "Machine_1";
    doc["totalTime_HMS"] = totalTime_HMS;

    readLinesSDON(SD, "/dataON.txt");
    delay(50);
    readLinesSDOFF(SD, "/dataOFF.txt");

    String requestBody;
    serializeJson(doc, requestBody);

    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(requestBody);
    flag = true;
    if (httpResponseCode > 0)
    {
      String response = http.getString();
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      Serial.println(response);
      deleteFile(SD, "/dataON.txt");
      deleteFile(SD, "/dataOFF.txt");

      //clearing temp arr - debug only
      for (int i = 0; i < numL; i++)
      {
        timesON[i] = "0";
        timesOFF[i] = "0";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.printf("Error occurred while sending HTTP POST");
    }
  }
```

Comment: For the second question: consider saving in binary format, for example in a struct. Given the exact size of the struct (eg sizeof()) it is easy to skip to another one. Advantage would be to save data until you are pretty sure it is transferred to the database. Deleting is not really necessary then, if you just use a boolean variable inside the struct to notify it is not to be used anymore. Reading lines is (could be) in my opinion too messy. In this way after sending you could check the data first before ‘deleting’.

Comment: I would wonder why it's taking 10 seconds to write a value to Postgres and try to fix that. Or change the server code to asynchronously write to Postgres and just return immediately.